# Make PhpStorm use same settings for all projects

Tags: php, phpstorm

I'm really wondering how I can just set and use the exact same settings for every single one of my PHP projects in PhpStorm.

I mean they really made this difficult. You'd think that a developer would want to use the exact same settings in every project, right?

Well apparently I have to re-set my settings for every single project. So annoying. How do I just make all my projects use the exact same settings without having to screw around every time I open a new project?

Comment: 1) What kind of settings? Concrete examples please. Because some are (or can be) IDE-wide (e.g. Code Style/Inspection Profile) and some are project-specific only. 2) Are we talking about new projects only or existing ones?

Comment: Why you not copy .idea folder to the new project to get your config?

Comment: Use the `Default settings` option instead of the standard `Settings`, https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2017.1/accessing-default-settings.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using the settings repository option.

Answer (score 3):

In File > Default Settings you can set the options that would be applied to all **new** projects created afterwards. Note that some settings are project-specific so you cannot make them default for every other project.